# running 2 samplers consecutively like a bundle in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, web-api-testing

I am trying to ensure that 2 samplers(A&B) in a thread are always ran consecutively like a bundle.
The thread group I wanted to do is:

[image]

where the controller makes sampler A&B a bundle and always runs them sequentially/consecutively, and where sampler C,D,E are other samplers in thread group 1.
and the desired results in chronological order should be similar to this:

[image]

in a way that no matter in what order the rest of the samplers are ran, B is always ran right after A is ran.

I have tried several controllers:

1. critical section controller would allow me to run B right after A everytime, however it seems that it cannot work with multiple threads and only works when I give enough ramp up time, and I don't find enough information that makes enough sense on this controller (please correct me if you have a better understanding of critical section controller)
2. loop controller would run B right after A only if I give enough ramp up time
3. interleave controller would run B right after A only if the only controller in the thread group

I have also read multiple posts on stackoverflow on this creating a bundle matter, however couldn't find a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

The samplers in a thread are executed in the order they appear in the tree.
I'm not sure if you want C, D and E to execute randomly in the same thread. If they are independent from A&B you can move them to other threadgroups.

[Execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

If you want to exclude all samples **from other threads** between A and B, you could try setting a property before A, and resetting it after B.
Also A and B should be in a Critical Section controller.
With an if controller you could check if the property is set, to exclude other samples between A and B.

With only one ThreadGroup I think something like this should work:

```
TG
  Critical Section
    sampler A
      preprocessor Set X=1
    sampler B
      postprocessor Set X=0
  if X!=1
    sampler C
  if X!=1
    sampler D
```

Comment: sometimes, instead of ABCDEAB it goes AAABBCDE, what I need is that A is always followed by B. the order of CDE is just random example of other controllers I am dealing with irrelevant of this question.

Comment: thanks for the answer! however what I'm looking for is more like excluding all samples from this thread group, as I want to make A&B run like a tight bundle(there is always a B right after an A, and there is always an A right before a B), regardless of any other thread configurations. @1010